# How to start a count in java from bottom-left corner?

Tags: java, arrays, counting, grib

[image]I know in java the top-left is considered the (0,0) coordinate. I am trying to count the pixel of a file. The file pixel's (0,0) coordinate, starts in the bottom-left corner.  The total overall area of the screen is 1121x881.  I need to count the pixels in order so that the data matches up with the coordinates. The area I want out of the 1121x881 is 543x451. Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: I don't understand where you are getting those dimensions from. Why not just iterate over the pixels in the order that you want to iterate them?

Comment: so the file pixels are 0,0 from the bottom left to the upper right.  and at each pixel there is a specific value I need.  but java expects to read in pixels from upper left to lower right, right?

Comment: Java does not expect to read anything in any order. You are the one that will tell Java how to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: It seems like the desired effect is a 543,451 start from the bottom left?

in that case:

```
w= //your desired width
h= //your desired height
for(int x=543; x<w+543; x++){
    for(y=(pic.height-451)+h; y<pic.height-h;y++){
       //count;
    }
}
```

This code starts at the bottom left, move up 451, over 543, and captures however wide and tall of a section as you specify.

---

instead of the standard

```
for(int x=0; x<pic.width; x++){
    for(y=0; y<pic.height;y++){
       //count;
    }
}
```

why not try

```
for(int x=0; x<pic.width; x++){
    for(y=pic.height; y>0;y--){
       //count;
    }
}
```

This will start the count from the bottom left hand corner and work upward, then to the left. By changing the limit of the loops, you can define the area you want.

If you want an area that is 543x451 with the bottom left corner the same as the original image you would do:

```
for(int x=0; x<543; x++){
    for(y=pic.height; y>451;y--){
       //count;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if the overall area is 1121x881 and the area I want is 543,451 through 703,591; so:
for(int x=543; x<703; x++){
    for(y=591; y>451; y--){
       //count;
    }
}
???

Comment: Oh, you didnt mention that you want a section with 543,451 as the bottom left corner. This will still work.

in the for loops, 
`x = (your bottom left corner x) x<(startx + width) x++`

`y = ((pic.height-desired bottom y)+height) y<(pic.height-bottom y) y++`